# How to Map String in A Dataframe from A Corresponding String List

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, mapping

suppose I have this dataframe A with particular column Tweet:

```
TWEET
-----
kamu ngajak gelut
dtnggu kedatangannya
dia jadi pampir
```

And there is another dataframe B, structured like this:

```
ORIGIN            TRANSFORMED 
-----------------------------
ngajak             mengajak
dtnggu             ditunggu
pamir              vampir
```

Is there a way to map the strings of dataframe A to dataframe B, so whenever there is a string match, words from TRANSFORMED column will replace corresponding string based on ORIGIN column in TWEET column? My desired result:

```
TWEET
-----
kamu mengajak gelut
ditunggu kedatangannya
dia jadi vampir
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: _Is there a way to map the strings of dataframe A to dataframe B, so whenever there is a string match, words from TRANSFORMED column will replace corresponding string based on ORIGIN column in TWEET column?_ Yes, most likely. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ORIGIN` column has **unique values**.

```py
In [88]: bstr = r''' 
    ...: ORIGIN TRANSFORMED 
    ...: ngajak             mengajak 
    ...: dtnggu             ditunggu 
    ...: pamir              vampir'''                                                                                                                                             

In [89]: astr = r''' 
    ...: TWEETS 
    ...: kamu ngajak gelut 
    ...: dtnggu kedatangannya 
    ...: dia jadi pampir'''                                                                                                                                                       

In [90]: dfa = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(astr), sep='\\n', engine='python')                                                                                                       

In [91]: dfb = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(bstr), sep='\\s+')                                                                                                                       

In [92]: def replace(word, lookup_df, search_col, ans_col): 
    ...:     match = lookup_df[search_col] == word 
    ...:     if match.any(): 
    ...:         return lookup_df[match][ans_col].values[0] 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         return word 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [93]: dfa['TWEETS'] = dfa['TWEETS'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join([replace(word, dfb, 'ORIGIN', 'TRANSFORMED') for word in row.split(' ')]))                                      

In [94]: dfa                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[94]: 
                   TWEETS
0     kamu mengajak gelut
1  ditunggu kedatangannya
2         dia jadi pampir
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

I've created two dataframe for your scenario with your datas.

df1:

```
data = '''kamu ngajak gelut dtnggu kedatangannya dia jadi pampir'''
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TWEET': [data]})
```

df2:

```
   ORIGIN TRANSFORMED
0  ngajak    mengajak
1  dtnggu    ditunggu
2  pampir      vampir
```

Code:

```
for or_word in df2['ORIGIN'].values.tolist():
    if any(df1['TWEET'].str.contains(or_word)):
        transformed_word = df2['TRANSFORMED'].iloc[df2.index[df2['ORIGIN'] == or_word].tolist()[0]]
        print(transformed_word)
        df1['TWEET'] = df1['TWEET'].str.replace(or_word, transformed_word)
```

Output:

```
['kamu mengajak gelut ditunggu kedatangannya dia jadi vampir']
```